# Another GCC make question

Tags: gcc

I installed gcc with Homebrew and I also did the following:

1. aliased both gcc and g++ with

```
alias gcc='gcc-10'
alias g++='g++-10'
```

2. Symlinked gcc and g++ to gcc-10 and g++-10 with

```
ln /usr/local/bin/gcc-10 /usr/local/bin/gcc
ln /usr/local/bin/g++-10 /usr/local/bin/g++
```

3. Also added /usr/local/bin to beginning of my path.

Still when compiling with make I get

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [plugins/gtc2vcf.so] Error 1
```

Nothing work unless I use `make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-10` and then it works.  Obviously it's the `/usr/bin/cc` that is getting called but is there a cc I can install with brew?  It's pretty confusing with all the `gcc/g++/c++/cc` stuff out there so please answer with explanation.

EDIT: okay so it's an anaconda3 issue.  They must have the wrong cc compiler and it was first in path so I can use anaconda python.

Comment: Why don't you just define the compiler to be used in your Makefile?

Comment: Should have clarified it's not my program.  I downloaded it from Github so I'd have to download it and edit every time.  Either way I'd be editing something to install it.

Comment: make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-10  is the usual way - under Unix there is no general position for where the C++ compiler is . This allows multiple compilers etc. As here you have gcc and clang++ SO I would just create a shell file to call that make command line. Don't rely on your PATH it will change

Comment: Use env variables to your advantage. They are there to be used.

Comment: @anki do you mean use alias or for example set CC=/path/to/gcc and then call make CC=$CC.  That really only shortens adding to make but I still have to tell make which CC to use.

Comment: @BrianWiley If CC is set as env var, it doesn't need to be mentioned in the invocation to make. Both do the same thing, and doing both at once is redundant.

Comment: @anki right but by `env var` do you mean add to my bashrc?  When I hear `env` is sounds like windows

Comment: @BrianWiley I have set CC and CXX in my .bash_profile. I can't comment for other systems. But yes, I mean adding `export CC=path/to/gcc` to something that is loaded in every shell windows/ tab.

Comment: So I have done all this and trying to compile a program.  It keeps blinking at top of terminal "gfortran f951 lang clang++".  I feel like it's impossible to force the Mac terminal to use GNU gcc?

Comment: It is perfectlk possible to use gcc Many poeople do. You need to provide the exact command line you use and other details. Also you later comments don't match the question. In the question you say it is fixed but comments suggest otherwise.